# How are variables shared between concurrent `session.run(...)` calls in tensorflow?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

If you make two concurrent calls to the same session, `sess.run(...)`, how are variables concurrently accessed in tensorflow?

Will each call see a snapshot of the variables as of the moment `run` was called, consistent throughout the call? Or will they see dynamic updates to the variables and only guarantee atomic updates to each variable?

I'm considering running test set evaluation on a separate CPU thread and want to verify that it's as trivial as running the inference op on a CPU device in parallel.

I'm having troubles figuring out exactly what guarantees are provided that make sessions "thread safe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some experimentation it appears that each call to `sess.run(...)` does indeed see a consistent point-in-time snapshot of the variables.

To test this I performed 2 big matrix multiply operations (taking about 10 sec each to complete), and updated a single, dependent, variable before, between, and after. In another thread I grabbed and printed that variable every 1/10th second to see if it picked up the change that occurred between operations while the first thread was still running. It did not, I only saw it's initial and final values. Therefore I conclude that variable changes are only visible outside of a specific call to `sess.run(...)` at the end of that run.

Comment: this is really nice to know, because I couldn't see a lot of information about the `sess.run` as thread-safe.